# How to get photos of a Flickr group organized

Tags: flickr

Is there a way to organize photos of a Flickr group? Now the pictures in our group are just one stream. For an individual account you have sets and collections.

UPDATE: A lot about this in the [Flickr forum](http://www.flickr.com/search/groups/?w=309584@N24&q=organize%20groups), but no real answer.

Answer (score 3):

One of the most important ways to organize photos within a group is using Flickr tags. They can help you in several ways:

- As an administrator, you may request that all photos which are added to the group pool have a specific tag. See, for example, the group rules of Our Daily Challenge: http://www.flickr.com/groups/ourdailychallenge/rules/. The group tag helps you to monitor the incoming pictures.
- You may request that your users add a topic-specific tag to pictures added to the group pool. See, for example, the challenges of the Digital Photography School: http://digital-photography-school.com/cute-weekly-photography-challenge
- In award groups, members are sometimes asked to tag their photos when they have received a specific number of awards.
  Note that, in many cases, users cannot only tag their own photos, but also those of others.

In addition to tags, discussions are often used to organize photos by topic. In this case, group members not only add their photos to the pool, they also add them to a specific discussion thread (again, you can check Our Daily Challenge for an example).

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to organize photos within a group.

You could have galleries maintained by an administrator (although they won't be linked to the group; you'd need to provide links in a sticky comment thread or the group description), but these are rather limited.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how photos can be organized once added to a group, but what I found is that if the pictures are organized first (say in an album), then batch uploading this set will add them to the group in that sequence.